# Byte to bits Operator Overloading C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been writing C++ a long time and maybe it's because I don't need to do this very often, but I seem to be lacking with regard to operator overloading.  I use it from time to time, but never needed to do what I wanted to do recently and found it somewhat problematic.

```
class foo
{
    public:
        static const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;
        uint8_t& operator[](const size_t& index) { return my_array[index >> 3]; }

        // problematic equality operator
        bool operator==(const size_t& index) const { return my_array[index >> 3] & (1 << (index & 7)); }
        //

        // Need an assignment operator to do:
        // my_array[index >> 3] |= 1 << (index & 7);
        // ^------------------^ might not needed as it's returned from [] operator

    private:
        std::array<uint8_t, (ARRAY_SIZE >> 3) + ((ARRAY_SIZE & 7) ? 1 : 0)> my_array;
};
```

Now as you can see from the above, what is being done here is to take a size_t number and store it in it's relative bit position.  So, 5 for instance would be stored in bit 4 of byte 0 and 9 would be stored in bit 1 of byte 1 in the array etc.

Now the subscript operator works fine and returns the correct byte from the array, but that left the problem of things like this:

```
if (foo[n])    // where n is a size_t integer representing a bit position
```

It then dawned on me that the above is an abbreviated form of:

```
if (foo[n] == true)
```

and so that led to me writing the above equality operator, but for some reason I don't understand, the operator isn't called.  I thought it would have been called following the subscript operator, or is it not called because it's not an object of type foo anymore?  What's the best way to fix this?  Is it to write an external operator== and make it a friend of foo?

Oh and some pointers regarding the construction of the assignment operator would be appreciated too.  Thanks very much...

**EDIT:**
      Thanks for all the help people.  I do think it's incredibly harsh to get downvoted for asking a question about something I didn't quite understand.  It's not like it was a stupid question or anything and if you re-read my original question properly, I did actually question that foo might not be the correct type after the subscript operator, that a few of you have pointed out.  Anyway, here's a bit more context.  I haven't had chance to properly study all the great replies...

I did originally write the operator like this, which did actually return the correct bit from the array.  Something someone has already pointed out.

```
bool operator[](const size_t index) const { return my_array[index >> 3] & (1 << (index & 7)); }
```

What I then had a problem with was setting the bits in the array:

```
foo f;

if (f[3])  // this is fine
```

But doing something like:

```
f[6] = true;
```

I guess what I was hoping for was a more elegant way of doing this than writing the following:-

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        static const size_t MAX_LIST_SIZE = 100000;
        bool get(const size_t index) const { return my_array[index >> 3] & (1 << (index & 7)); }
        void set(const size_t index) { my_array[index >> 3] |= 1 << (index & 7); }
    private:
        std::array<uint8_t, ((MAX_LIST_SIZE >> 3) + ((MAX_LIST_SIZE & 7) ? 1 : 0))> my_array;
}
```

and then using the class like this:

```
Foo f
f.set(10);
if (f.get(10))
    ...
```

I just thought it would be easier to overload the operators, but from the look of it, it seems more cumbersome.  (Oh and someone asked why I used uint8_t rather than bool, well this is because on this particular platform, bool is actually 32bits!)

Comment: "_It then dawned on me that the above is an abbreviated form of_" No, not really. Any non-zero value is evaluated as being true-y, while `true` is a specific value (on most platforms that I've seen = 1). So `if (foo[n])` is more equivalent to `if (foo[n] != false)`.

Comment: `It then dawned on me that the above is an abbreviated form` - no it isn't  - whatever foo() returns is treated as a boolean, but there is no call to operator==.

Comment: Also, your `operator[]` is returning a reference to a temporary, which... I'm surprised even compiles. Even if that magically worked, you're returning the bit, _and up to seven bits to it's left_, which the caller will then modify.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset`?

Comment: _It then dawned on me that the above is an abbreviated form of: `if (foo[n] == true)`_ if this were true, then this last expressions would be the abbreviated form of `if ((foo[n] == true) == true)`, and so on... Also, even if this was the case, why should it invoke `operator==` over `foo`? The return value of your `operator[]` is an `uint8_t`, `foo` is completely out of the picture.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah sorry, didn't give enough context.  It's not a reference to a temporary, see my edits and the reason it's not a vector<bool> is that bool on this platform is 32bits and if I'd used vector, I'd needed to have done a reserve().  Makes more sense to use a static array in this case methinks.

Comment: @TheWelder `std::vector<bool>` already implements the "bit vector" optimization, so it's not like it's going to be relevant for memory usage. Also, for similar semantics you wouldn't need `reserve`, but `resize` (or just calling the right constructor). As for using a static array, you are making your object 100 KB big, allocating several of it on the stack is going to be problematic.

Comment: Yeah, I meant resize() rather than reserve() and I know I could use a constructor to get the correct size.  And yes, std::vector<bool> does has the bit packing optimization, but does it look like I'm using std::vector<bool>?  I'm using std::array which **does not** pack bits like std::vector<bool> does.  Everyone seems intent on me changing std::array to std::vector<bool>.  Come on, I could have used std::bitset if I'd wanted, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have several deep-ish misunderstandings.

> Now the subscript operator works fine and returns the correct byte
> from the array, but that left the problem of things like this:
>
> ```
> if (foo[n])    // where n is a size_t integer representing a bit position
> ```

Your problem here is not the `if` *per se*; it's that you are returning the wrong thing. If you are building a packed bit set, your `operator[]` should just return the value of the bit at the requested position. So:

```
 bool operator[](size_t index) { return (my_array[index >> 3]) & (1<<(index&7)); }
```

and here your `if`, as well as any other operation involving your `operator[]`, will work as expected.

---

> It then dawned on me that the above is an abbreviated form of:
>
> ```
> if (foo[n] == true)
> ```

It is not. `if` evaluates the expression insides the parentheses, and (essentially) casts it to a boolean; if the result is `true`, it executes the branch, otherwise it does not.

> and so that led to me writing the above equality operator, but for some reason I don't understand, the operator isn't called.

The operator isn't called because:

1. as explained above, the `operator==` is never involved in `if (foo[n])`;
2. even if you explicitly wrote `if (foo[n]==true)`, your operator wouldn't be invoked, because *once your `operator[]` returns, `foo` is no longer involved*.

Think about it: even in your "original" `operator[]` you return a reference to `uint8_t`. The statement:

```
if (a[n] == true)
```

(with `a` being of type `foo`)

is effectively the same as:

```
uint8_t &temp = a[n];
if (temp == true)
```

Now, in the expression `temp == true` the type of `a` is never mentioned - there's only `temp`, which is an `uint8_t&`, independently of how it was ever obtained, and `true`, a `bool` literal. Your `operator==` would be considered if you were comparing `a` with a `size_t`, but that would make no sense.

---

Finally, about your comment:

> ```
>     // Need an assignment operator to do:
>     // my_array[index >> 3] |= 1 << (index & 7);
>     // ^------------------^ might not needed as it's returned from [] operator
> ```

this, again, won't work for the exact same reason - you need an operator overload to work *on the return value of `operator[]`*, not on the `foo` class itself.

This is generally accomplished by having `operator[]` return not the value itself, but a proxy object, which remembers its parent and the requested index, and provides its own `operator==` and `operator=` that perform what you were trying to put straight in the `foo` class (along with extra operators that make it possible to it to pass for a reference to a boolean).

Something like:

```
struct PackedBitVector {
    static const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;
    struct ElementProxy {
        PackedBitVector &parent;
        size_t idx;

        operator bool() const { return parent.data[idx>>3] & (1<<(idx&7)) }
        bool operator==(bool other) const { return bool(*this) == other; }
        bool operator!=(bool other) const { return !(*this == other); }
        ElementProxy &operator=(bool other) {
            if(other) parent.data[idx>>3] |= 1<<(idx&7);
            else      parent.data[idx>>3] &= ~(1<<(idx&7));
            return *this;
        }
    }:
    ElementProxy operator[](size_t index) { return ElementProxy{*this, index}; }

private:
    std::array<uint8_t, (ARRAY_SIZE >> 3) + ((ARRAY_SIZE & 7) ? 1 : 0)> data;
};
```

To make this work in general you'd have to add a full bucket of other operators, so that this proxy object could credibly pass as a reference to a `bool`, which is what `std::vector<bool>` does.

About this, from your remark about `bool` being 32 bit wide on your platform you seem not to know that `std::vector<bool>` already sports this "packed bit array" space optimization, so you could directly use it, without reimplementing a broken version of the real thing.

Comment: The moment you pointed out using a proxy object, I knew how to do it.  I was hoping for an elegant operator solution as per by get/set methods above, which aren't a "broken version of the real thing", they work perfectly well.  And actually I didn't know that vector<bool> stored things as packed bits, but IMHO this is an "aberration", having this forced on you and possibly shouldn't be relied on.  Moreover, I was using std::array, not std::vector which I'm pretty sure doesn't pack bools bitwise.  If I'd wanted to use std::vector, then I would have.  I do feel like I've been laid into a bit!

Comment: The "broken version of the real thing" was about the reimplementation of `std::vector<bool>`, not of the `get()`/`set()` methods, which are a perfectly fine way of implementing this. About `std::vector<bool>`, indeed it is widely considered a misfeature, but it is there and it is contractual, so for once that it's desired you can fully rely on it!  `std::array` fortunately doesn't do this. My point about mentioning `std::vector` was: if you are implementing your own thing because you want it packed to save memory, fear not, as `std::vector<bool>` has you covered already.

Comment: Thanks. I do feel like I've been a bit clubbed over the head for asking this question. I guess I should have thought a lot more how to word it properly. The bottom line was, I was hoping that I could use operators to provide the same functionality as the get/set I wrote with the same level of ease and be a bit more elegant. It just turns out not to be the case. But I appreciate everyone's feedback though.